# Middleware for user roles in Laravel

Tags: laravel, middleware

I am creating an Admin Panel and I have problem with the access , I am using One-to-Many relation and I have the table user with `role_id=3`.

This middleware works correctly but I need to protect the routes correctly.

```
class Administrador
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('/administrador');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The routes are correctly set, but I don't know how to send the user's role in this Middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...

**EDIT**

If you want to combine in one middleware `Administrador` it would be:

```
class Administrador
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles = null, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('/administrador');
            }
        }

        $roles = explode('|', $roles);

        if (! in_array(Auth::guard($guard)->user()->role_id, $roles) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Example usage on route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'administrador:1|2'], function () {});
```

`administrador:1|2` replace the value with your role ids separated by `|`, if you want to use another `guard` then you can pass it as second parameter, example: `administrador:1|2,custom_guard`. This way you can define multiple roles that able to access your admin screen.

If you would rather want to use one fixed role:

```
class Administrador
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('/administrador');
            }
        }

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->user()->role_id !== 3) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```